# How to reduce the number of tick labels on a bar plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart, axis-labels, x-axis

The following bar graph is too cluttered on the x axis.

Is there a manner in which I can increment my ticks? Instead of showing every tick between 18-55, it increments by 3 or 5 (or more) so it looks nicer? I noticed that when I ran a line plot, it incremented automatically by 10.**

```
import matplotlib as mpl
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

agesx = [18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35,
          36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55]

py_devy = [20046, 17100, 20000, 24744, 30500, 37732, 41247, 45372, 48876, 53850, 57287, 63016, 65998, 70003, 70000, 71496, 75370, 83640, 84666,
            84392, 78254, 85000, 87038, 91991, 100000, 94796, 97962, 93302, 99240, 102736, 112285, 100771, 104708, 108423, 101407, 112542, 122870, 120000]

js_devy = [16446, 16791, 18942, 21780, 25704, 29000, 34372, 37810, 43515, 46823, 49293, 53437, 56373, 62375, 66674, 68745, 68746, 74583, 79000,
            78508, 79996, 80403, 83820, 88833, 91660, 87892, 96243, 90000, 99313, 91660, 102264, 100000, 100000, 91660, 99240, 108000, 105000, 104000]

all_devy = [17784, 16500, 18012, 20628, 25206, 30252, 34368, 38496, 42000, 46752, 49320, 53200, 56000, 62316, 64928, 67317, 68748, 73752, 77232,
         78000, 78508, 79536, 82488, 88935, 90000, 90056, 95000, 90000, 91633, 91660, 98150, 98964, 100000, 98988, 100000, 108923, 105000, 103117]

width = 0.25
x_indexes = np.arange(len(agesx))
 
plt.xticks(ticks=x_indexes,labels=agesx)

plt.style.use("seaborn-dark")
plt.bar(x_indexes-width, all_devy, width=width, label= "All Devs")
plt.bar(x_indexes,py_devy,width=width, label= "Python Devs")
plt.bar(x_indexes + width, js_devy, width=width, label= "Javascript Dev")

plt.title("Median Developer Salaries by Age (USD)")
plt.xlabel("Ages")
plt.ylabel("Salary (USD)")
plt.tight_layout()

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

This results in the following graph:

[image: Graph1]

Initially I thought that I could solve this just by

```
plt.xticks(np.arange(18,55,3))
```

However it results in this output:

[image: AttemptedGraph]

How can I modify this to get the graph to begin at 18 as opposed to starting the tick at position 18?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- The question uses the [implicit "pyplot" interface](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/api_interfaces.html#the-implicit-pyplot-interface), as such, two easy options are:

  1. Increase the width of the figure with:

     - [`fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.figure.html)
     - `plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))`.
  2. Set the number of ticks with [`plt.xticks`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xticks.html)
- **Tested in `python 3.11.2`, `pandas 2.0.1`, `matplotlib 3.7.1`**

### 1. Increase Figure Size

```py
# increase the figure size
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))

plt.bar(x_indexes-width, all_devy, width=width, label= "All Devs")
plt.bar(x_indexes,py_devy,width=width, label= "Python Devs")
plt.bar(x_indexes + width, js_devy, width=width, label= "Javascript Dev")
_ = plt.xticks(ticks=x_indexes, labels=agesx)
```

[image]

### 2. Specify the xtick labels with `plt.xticks`

- `plt.xticks(np.arange(18, 55, 3))` didn't work because, unlike a line plot, bar plot ticks are 0 indexed. `print(plt.gca().get_xticklabels())` shows `'18'` at index `0`.

  - You preset the ticks and labels with `plt.xticks(ticks=x_indexes, labels=agesx)`
  - `[v if i%2 == 0 else '' for i, v in enumerate(agesx)]` uses a list-comprehension to set every other label to an empty string.

    - Increase 2, for fewer tick labels.

```py
plt.bar(x_indexes-width, all_devy, width=width, label= "All Devs")
plt.bar(x_indexes,py_devy,width=width, label= "Python Devs")
plt.bar(x_indexes + width, js_devy, width=width, label= "Javascript Dev")

# adjust the frequency of the visible labels; the number of ticks and labels must be the same
_ = plt.xticks(ticks=range(len(agesx)), labels=[v if i%2 == 0 else '' for i, v in enumerate(agesx)])
```

[image]

---

- Alternatively, use pandas, which makes grouped, and stacked bar plots easier. `matplotlib` is the default backend for [`pandas.DataFrame.plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html).

  - The following examples assign the returned [`matplotlib.axes.Axes`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.html) to `ax`, which is the [explicit "Axes" interface](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/api_interfaces.html#the-explicit-axes-interface).

```py
import pandas as pd

# load data to pandas
data = {'Python Devs': py_devy, 'Javascript Devs': js_devy, 'All Devs': all_devy}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, index=agesx)

# 1. plot the bars with rotated labels
ax = df.plot(kind='bar', width=0.85, rot=90)

# 2. plot with increased figure size
ax = df.plot(kind='bar', width=0.85, figsize=(10, 6), rot=0)

# 3. plot horizontal bars, which may be better for many bars, and long labels
ax = df.plot(kind='barh', width=0.85, figsize=(6, 7))

# 4. every other tick label
ax = df.plot(kind='bar', width=0.85, rot=0, xticks=range(len(df.index))[::2])
_ = ax.set_xticklabels(df.index[::2])
```

[plot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BMHwn.png) [plot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VjJT4.png) [plot3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0yA9B.png) [plot4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lCQti.png)

`df.head()`

```
    Python Devs  Javascript Devs  All Devs
18        20046            16446     17784
19        17100            16791     16500
20        20000            18942     18012
21        24744            21780     20628
22        30500            25704     25206
```

Answer (score 1):

> The following bar graph is too cluttered on the x axis.

IMHO the clutter is Matplotlib trying to tell you that your graph is quite crowded.

[image: running mean]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

agesx = [18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55]
py_devy =  [20046, 17100, 20000, 24744, 30500, 37732, 41247, 45372, 48876, 53850, 57287, 63016, 65998, 70003, 70000, 71496, 75370, 83640, 84666, 84392, 78254, 85000, 87038, 91991, 100000, 94796, 97962, 93302, 99240, 102736, 112285, 100771, 104708, 108423, 101407, 112542, 122870, 120000]
js_devy =  [16446, 16791, 18942, 21780, 25704, 29000, 34372, 37810, 43515, 46823, 49293, 53437, 56373, 62375, 66674, 68745, 68746, 74583, 79000, 78508, 79996, 80403, 83820, 88833, 91660, 87892, 96243, 90000, 99313, 91660, 102264, 100000, 100000, 91660, 99240, 108000, 105000, 104000]
all_devy = [17784, 16500, 18012, 20628, 25206, 30252, 34368, 38496, 42000, 46752, 49320, 53200, 56000, 62316, 64928, 67317, 68748, 73752, 77232, 78000, 78508, 79536, 82488, 88935, 90000, 90056, 95000, 90000, 91633, 91660, 98150, 98964, 100000, 98988, 100000, 108923, 105000, 103117]

rmean = lambda l,n:[sum(t)/n for t in zip(*(l[i:]for i in range(n)))]
N = 5

plt.style.use("seaborn-v0_8-dark")
for y, label in zip((py_devy,js_devy,all_devy),
                  'Python JavaScript all'.split()):
     plt.plot(rmean(agesx, N), rmean(y, N), label=label+' devs')
plt.ylim((-1000, 120000))
plt.grid()
plt.legend()
plt.xlabel('Central Age for the running mean')
plt.ylabel('Median Salary, €')
plt.suptitle('              Median Developer Salary')
plt.title('— running mean over %d age classes —'%N, size='small')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```